# Options for upgrading from Magento CE 1.6 to CE 1.9 and bringing customer records across

Tags: magento-1.6, upgrade, ce-1.9.0.1

I have a 2.5 year old Magento CE 1.6 site that I would like to upgrade to CE 1.9.

Due to changes within a number of areas - theme, extensions I am using, attribute sets etc. - I am in the process of starting from scratch on the Magento CE 1.9 site.

The only issue I have is that I want the customer records to come across to the new site without resetting their passwords.

From what I can see the encryption method of the customer passwords has changed from 1.6 to 1.9, so even with the same encryption key, I am not sure if this would work.

Is this, in any way, possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply upgrade the database and capture all your data without any migration. If you follow the steps here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

You will upgrade using a fresh version of Magento 1.9. Then you can move in any modules you still need/want.

You can then style you theme from the included Responsive theme in 1.9

Comment: Simple! thank you very much, I'll post results on this